# Rewrite image URLs to serve securely

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I've found the following regex. Given that I'm completely clueless on how to work with regexes, can someone help to point me in the write direction of combining them?

```
(/!\[([\S\s]*?)\]\(http:\/\/(\S*?)\)/, '![$1](https://$2)')
```

This regex would rewrite http:// URLs to serve over https://
Due to some issues with sites we link to, I'd like to ensure that instead of every URL being rewritten to serve from https:// only those links which are directly to images would be served.

I've found this regex which seems to check that the URL is an image

```
/^https?:\/\/(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)‌​$/i
```

How should these be combined?

Comment: What context is this code being run in? Browser? Server?

Comment: @tadman, this would need to run on the server (Node)

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I would rephrase this question and ask about the problem you are really trying to solve.

Comment: @dave I mostly agree but it's also nice to see what he's tried. In future it'd probably be better for him to ask about his real problem, and include this stuff as some extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the syntax you'd use in Node.js, but here's the regex that would probably work (in the same format as your first example).

```
(/^http:\/\/((?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:\/[^\/#?]+)+\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)‌)​$/i, 'https://$1')
```

Your first regex seems to deal specifically with markdown-like formats. Your second regex is actually reasonably good (maybe more complex than necessary even) so I used most of it.